# Unique Values from Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, xajax

Hello I am trying to validate an array and insert into it from a textbox.

but I do not want to insert duplicate values.

e.g

```
 ######### Inserting first name #####
 $textbox = 'Jose,';

 $textarea = Array();

 $list = explode(',', $list, -1);

  foreach(array_unique($list) as $key){
 if ($textbox != $key){
    insert (Jose,)into textarea;
 }  
 }
```

(exit)

```
 ########### second name ######
  $textbox = 'Carlos,';

  $textarea = Array('Jose,');

  $list = explode(',' $list, -1);

  foreach(array_unique($list) as $key){
  if($textbox != $key){
     insert (Carlos,) into textarea;
  }
  }
```

(exit)

```
  ########### third name ######
   $textbox = 'Carlos,';

   $textarea = Array('Jose,Carlos,');

   $list = explode(',' $list, -1);

   foreach(array_unique($list) as $key){ 
   if($Carlos != $key){ //$key = Jose
     insert (Carlos,) into textarea;
   } //next
   if($Carlos != $key){ //$key = Carlos
       insert (Carlos,) into textarea;
   }else{
     It exist;
   } 
 }
```

(exit)

here is my code...

```
   foreach ( array_unique($viewer) as $viewermi ){
         if ( $userdata['uid'] != $viewermi ){ 
         $objResponse->addAppend('viewerlist', 'value', $userdata['uid'].',');
         $objResponse->addAssign('vieadded', 'value', '');
         $objResponse->addAssign('vadded', 'innerHTML', $user.' Added');
         $objResponse->addScript('$(\'#btViewAdded\').attr(\'disabled\', true)');
         }else{
        $objResponse->addAssign('vadded', 'innerHTML', '');
        $objResponse->addAlert("It uid had been added! ".$viewermi);
        $objResponse->addAssign('vieadded', 'value', '');
        $objResponse->addScript('$(\'#btViewAdded\').attr(\'disabled\', true)');
    } // End If-Else $userdata
 } // End foreach Viewers
```

anyone could help me with this ?

I have tried a few of ways, but I could not do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $textbox = 'Carlos,Jose,Carlos,Lauro,Marcos';

  $textarea = array();

  $list = explode(',' , $textbox);

  foreach(array_unique($list) as $key){
     if(!in_array($key , $textarea)){
      $textarea[] = $key;
     }
  }
```

Comment: if I write.... 'Alejandro' first it check...

'alejandro' != Carlos ?
insert 'alejandro'

$textbox = 'Carlos,Jose,Carlos,Lauro,Marcos,Alejandro';
## Then---
'Alejandro' != 'Jose' ?
insert 'alejandro'
$textbox = 'Carlos,Jose,Carlos,Lauro,Marcos,Alejandro,Alejandro';

Comment: No, array_unique function will make the work to eliminate all duplicate entry from the array, so list will contain just carlos,jose,lauro and marocs no 2 times carlos, the in_array function will check if the name already is in textarea array. so this way your textarea never will get duplicate entry.

Comment: Oooh. I got it.... I first check if textarea has any entry... if it has 1 or more... I compare with textbox... if it is different, I add textbox value to textarea. then i want to add another one. e.g  textarea = 'juan,carlos';  textbox = 'carlos'; #####--- First check 'carlos' != juan ? yes-> add carlos... now #-- textarea = 'juan,carlos,carlos'; ## 'carlos' != 'carlos' ? no... n/a.